# Как использовать HTML теги в CSS (content)

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте,хотел бы узнать каким образом можно использовать HTML теги в поле CSS (content).
Вот код

```
.hello {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000000;
}
.timer:after {
  content: "<span id="Hello" class="Hello">Привет</span>";
  content: "Бла бла бла : ";
}
```

Comment: @Fike,не хочет работать.

Comment: @VLADPRO100LORD, а я с самим кодом ничего и не делал, только отформатировал

Comment: Ещё можно в Hex писать [инфа на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190396/adding-html-entities-using-css-content)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В content не допускается html, только текст. Собственно сам css к html привязан только условно, css может задавать стили чего угодно. Вообще, если в after пихается невпихуемое, то, скорее всего, надо шаблон менять, а не html, after - это проставить красную звездочку всем `label.required`, например.

Comment: @Fike,привет.Можешь помочь пожалуйста в этой теме : http://hashcode.ru/questions/303995/html-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE

Answer (score 2):

Ну как минимум надо использовать разные типы кавычек, а так да, любой текст в content будет представлен как текст.

```
content: "<span id='Hello' class='Hello'>Привет</span>";
```

Comment: Я может быть чего-то в этой жизни не понимаю, но мне всегда казалось что контент вставленный через content как html интерпретироваться не должен. И это правильно ибо:

   .boom { content: "<b class='boom'>BOOM!!!</b>" }

Улавливаешь?

Comment: В исходном коде все что в content - не видно! Имейте это ввиду.

Answer (score 2):

Да пишите себе на здоровье, но не пихайте туда теги HTML, им там не место. Принцип - мухи отдельно, а котлеты отдельно. Пример, мне надо на `ul`, добавить свой `list-items` и покрасить его и выравнять, нет проблем, я пишу, что у меня l`ist-items` нет, но `li:after` я вставляю  `content:"✔ ";` и в придачу, размер шрифта и цвет и все фантасмагории, что вы придумаете. Так я имею красивую галку в content, единственное правило - в стили пихаем только юникод

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете вставить разве что картинку с изображением, на котором будет отформатированный текст, используя конструкцию `content: url(...)`
Но теги в `content` будут интерпретироваться исключительно как текст.